# Кириллица в HTML в Spring MVC проекте

Tags: java, html, spring, intellij-idea

Делаю свой  сайт на спринге. Всё работает. Но когда в темплейте HTML пишу русские буквы, на странице выводит ???? .  Если возьму данные из базы с русским текстом и отправлю на вью, все выводит нормально. Но как только беру HTML и пишу в нем кириллицей, на вью знаки вопроса.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

есть. Файл с html в utf-8.

Пример контроллера:

```
 @GetMapping
    public ModelAndView showCheckList() {
        String text = "тестовый текст";
        System.out.println(text);
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.addObject("test",text);
        modelAndView.setViewName("shop/CheckList");    
        return modelAndView;    
    }
```

В консоль все выведет нормально. Но в HTML будет ????. Точно так же будет если я прямо в HTML напишу русский текст.
В самой идее стоит кодировка utf-8 и для нее и для проекта.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928046/spring-mvc-utf-8-encoding

Answer (score 0):

можно еще попробовать в htaccess добавить

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

Comment: Где это добавлять?

Comment: в htaccess после 
RewriteEngine On в каталоге с index.php

Comment: как пхп относится к Java и Spring mvc?

Comment: я index.php для примера назвал, а так htaccess в точке входа в Ваше приложение